# How to implement continuous loop for npm package script

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm

My code is

My index.js script is as follows:

```
import personfaces from './dist/index';

const dnte = new personfaces();

dnte.getImage({ width: 256, height: 256, type: 'file' })
.then(res => { console.log('result->', res); })
.catch(err => { console.log('error->', err); });
```

I run the code  using terminal command "npm start" but I want to make this as a continuous repetitive loop for say 100 runs.
Each time I run the code at my terminal, it downloads an image and I want it to be a continuous process with 100 runs so that it generates 100 images.

is there a way to run terminal command 100 runs or add 100 runs to my main code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but for that matter you don't need it. You have to run your function a hundred times. Otherwise you can create a bash file and run it according to your operating system and run ‍‍`npm start` code every time. job or schedule in OS.

But the simplest way is to use a recursive function.

```
import personfaces from './dist/index';

const dnte = new personfaces();

var count = 100
recursiveFun(0);
function recursiveFun(index) {
  if (index === count)
    return;
  dnte.getImage({ width: 256, height: 256, type: 'file' })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('result->', res);
      recursiveFun(index + 1)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error->', err);
      recursiveFun(index)
    });
}
```

second way is using node module:

The [p-iteration](https://github.com/toniov/p-iteration) module on npm implements the Array iteration methods so they can be used in a very straightforward way with async/await.

Loop through an array to execute asynchronous actions on each element.
Sometimes you must execute an [asynchronous action on each elements of an array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-async-loop), but you must wait for the previous action to complete before proceed to the next.